# Error with upgrade to aurelia app clie3.01 with webpack 5.7

Tags: aurelia, webpack-5

We recently trying to upgrade really old aurelia app to use latest webpack and aurelia cli.

am getting following error when i try to use bundles generated for webpack 5.70

TypeError: e.ConsoleAppender is not a constructor y https://localhost:44376/Render/js/common.8b16d58387793d052fd8.bundle.js?v=9gvb5vLaGQeyQeNpKB6akAkiraOklLPKx1fVO5E9l8M:2 promise callback*aurelia-framework/e.prototype.developmentLogging/y</< https://localhost:44376/Render/js/common.8b16d58387793d052fd8.bundle.js?=9gvb5vLaGQeyQeNpKB6akAkiraOklLPKx1fVO5E9l8M:2
promise callback*aurelia-framework/e.prototype.developmentLogging/y<https://localhost:44376/Render/js/common.8b16d58387793d052fd8.bundle.js?v=9gvb5vLaGQeyQeNpKB6akAkiraOklLPKx1fVO5E9l8M:2